# How drupal handles block['content']?

Tags: blocks

I am trying to customize a module([quicktabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs)) for my need. In the *hook_block_view*, the `block['content']` contains an associative array of the contents.
Is there an existing drupal call that renders the associative array in *block['content']*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7)

> Renders HTML given a structured array tree.
>
> Recursively iterates over each of the array elements, generating HTML code.

There's much more explanation, and examples, on the docs page.

I'd advise also reading through [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760) to get a better idea of what that array represents.